# React/Redux: one onChange handler for multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to build a single onChange handler function to use with multiple form fields. The handler will dispatch actions to update a redux store. Here is what I have so far:

```
export default class Referrals extends React.Component {

  render() {
  return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Modal.Content >
      <Form>
        <Form.Input
          name='referral_1_name'
          onChange={e => this.props.dispatchUpdateStateData(e.target.value, 'var1')}
            />
        <button>Next</button>
      </Form>

    </Modal.Content>
  </React.Fragment>
  )}}
```

Here is how I setup the action, dispatcher, and the reducer:

```
// App.js
const map_dispatch_to_props = (dispatch, own_props) => {
  return {
    dispatchUpdateStateData : (stateData, stateVariable) => (
      dispatch(updateStateData(stateData, stateVariable)))
  }
};
const map_state_to_props = (state) => {
  return {
    // irrelevant state vars removed
  }
};

export const AppWrapped = connect(map_state_to_props,
   map_dispatch_to_props)(App);


// actions.js
export const updateStateData = (stateData, stateVariable) => {
  return {
    type : 'stateUpdate',
    payload : {
      stateVariable,
      stateData
    }
  }
};


// reducer.js
const starting_state = {
  var1 : ''
};

const reducer = (previous_state = starting_state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case 'stateUpdate':
      return {
        ...previous_state,
        [action.payload.stateVariable] : action.payload.stateData
      };
    default:
      return previous_state;
  }
};
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: _this2.props.dispatchUpdateStateData is not a function
onChange
src/components/Referrals.js:42
  39 |   placeholder='Name of Friend/Family Member'
  40 |   name='referral_1_name'
  41 |   style={{ marginBottom: '1vh', width: "265px" }}
> 42 |   onChange={e => this.props.dispatchUpdateStateData(e.target.value, 'var1')}
     | ^  43 | />
  44 | <Form.Input
  45 |   placeholder="This Person's Email"
```

I have only seen code samples control one input with one handler so am curious if one handler controlling several input fields is possible like I am attempting.

Comment: Can you show how you're actually connecting the component?  Are you sure you're using the connected version, and not the "plain" version?  Also, FYI, you can simplify the `mapDispatch` declaration [using the "object shorthand" form](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object), like: `const mapDispatch = {dispatchUpdateStateData  : updateStateData}`.

Comment: And yes, you can absolutely have a single change handler for multiple fields.  I show examples of this in my ["Practical Redux" tutorial series](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/series/practical-redux).

Comment: Good to know! I have updated my App.js to show the use of connect(). Other state variables are being passed down to other components correctly.

Comment: And can you show where you're actually _importing_ this component, and how you're rendering it?  My first guess is that you're using the unconnected version, not the connected version.

Comment: Waaaait a minute.  You're connecting `App`, but are you actually connecting `Referrals`? If not, is `App` passing down any props to `Referrals?

Comment: You caught it ;) I didn't pass down the dispatcher as a prop. It works now; thank you!